# Protected attribute and inheritance java

Tags: java, attributes, parameter-passing

i'm new to Java and i can't understand why in the c3.java i get an error in ref.x=1. x is declared as a protected attribute so methods of classes that inherit from c1 should be able to use any x of any object of type c1. How is that wrong ? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I28iv.png)

Comment: What method? `C4` doesn't inherit from anything. Why should it have access to protected members of another class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the method takes in a C1 object as an argument. This means that the class can't change it's value. The method shouldn't have access to the protected attributes of an object. Protected just means that the attributes are inherited, and they only exist within objects of the class that is inheriting. So since C3 inherits from C1, C3 has x as a protected variable, **but it can only be modified within the methods of the class.** Since C1 is being passed as an argument to the method in class C3, you aren't in the class C1, and therefore the x variable for a C1 object cannot be modified.